# Obtener útimo id disponible en tabla

Tags: sql, postgresql

Quería saber la forma de poder meter una nueva fila en una tabla y que el Id lo tome como el siguiente id disponible.

Actualmente estaba usando

```
nextval('dispositivos_id_seq'::regclass)
```

Comment: Cuando dices que no funciona a que te refieras da algun error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al momento de crear tu tablas deber decirle que su valor por `default` sera tomado de una secuencia:

```
 CREATE TABLE public.prueba
 (
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 
  nextval('prueba_id_seq'::regclass)
 );
```

Para esto ya tiene que existir tu secuencia la cual puede crear de la siguiente manera:

```
  CREATE SEQUENCE public.prueba_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
```

Nota: `public` es nombre del esquema puede variar de acuerdo a tu necesidad

Answer (score 1):

Ten en cuenta que para que tu código funcione es necesario que exista la secuencia que estás referenciando, en este caso deberías haber ejecutado el comando de creación inicialmente:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dispositivos_id_seq;
```

La secuencia automáticamente se creará con 0 como valor inicial, en caso de que necesites inicializarla en un valor específico solo cambia un poco la instrucción:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dispositivos_id_seq START WITH valor;
```

Para una guía completa de como ejecutar este comando, ingresa a [este link](https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/postgresqlya/temarios/descripcion.php?inicio=50&cod=228&punto=70).

Espero que haya sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Para seleccionar el siguiente valor de una secuencia ya creada se utiliza la siguiente sentencia:

```
SELECT NEXTVAL('nombreEsquema.nombreSecuencia');
```

**EDIT**

en el caso de que la secuencia no funcione por un X motivo, podrías utilizar el comando:

```
select max(id) from nombreEsquema.nombreTabla
```

con eso obtienes el último id ingresado.